# How to export two modules/namespaces with same name from multiple files in typescript in index.d.ts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, export

I'm building a new npm package, I have two different typescript files, they contain namespaces and modules with same name 'X'
at the end of each file i declare :

```
export default X;
```

I want to import them both into `index.d.ts` file and export them so the outer files (the files that import this repository/package) can import and use `X` modules and namespaces

But when I import them both:

```
import X from "./file1"
import X from "./file2"
```

I get this error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'X'
```

Is there a way to have the same namespace in two different typescript file and export them to outer packages?

Comment: `export { default as myX1 } from "./file1.ts";`?

Comment: When I try to export both the same way you did, I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is - using aliases.

**file1.ts**

```
class A{}
export default A;
```

**file2.ts**

```
class A{}
export default A;
```

**index.ts**

```
import { default as firstOne } from './file1';
import { default as secondOne } from './file2';
console.log(firstOne, secondOne);
```

Comment: I want to import and export the both modules with their original name 'X' and not change their names